# Why does an absolutely positioned span not position properly in a relatively positioned span in Firefox unless displayed as inline-block or the like?

Tags: html, css, firefox, absolute

I'd like to know why the following code is not rendered properly in FF unless I make the parent `span` display as a `inline-block` or the like. If you check the layout of the absolutely positioned span in the inspector it will show the number 184 instead of 197 on the right side. Once we add `display:inline-block` to the parent span it works fine.

```
<span style="position:relative; font-size:52px;">FOO BAR
  <span style="position:absolute; top:-17px; right:197px; height:22px; width:22px; background-color:black"></span>
</span>

<span style="position:relative; font-size:52px; display:inline-block">FOO BAR
  <span style="position:absolute; top:-17px; right:197px; height:22px; width:22px; background-color:black"></span>
</span>
```

Other browsers can handle it.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amayem/e1rs7r2p/3/)

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's bug. The width of the relative box is being computed including the space at the end. But according to the CSS whitespace rules the space at the end of a line (which it is) should be discarded.
You can see this because if you manually remove the spaces  - i.e. use

```
<span style="position:relative; font-size:52px;">FOO BAR<span 
  style="position:absolute; top:-17px; right:197px; height:22px; 
  width:22px; background-color:black"></span></span>
```

the box will be placed in FF similarly to the other browsers.

See http://jsfiddle.net/fg9enk2t/1/

---

<sub>Curiously, this end space rule causes all kinds of problems. I've seen bugs in both Chrome and IE when it comes to discarding spaces at the end of lines.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space in the html.

The difference is that a inline-block element gets rid of spaces (according to `white-space` property) at its beginning and end, but an inline element doesn't.

Assuming this CSS:

```css
.outer {
    position:relative;
    font-size:52px;
    outline: 1px solid;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:-17px;
    right:0px;
    height:22px;
    width:22px;
    background-color:black;
}
.ib {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then, the following will look like the same ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73opLnrq/)):

```
<span class="outer ib">FOO BAR<span class="inner"></span></span>
```

```
<span class="outer">FOO BAR<span class="inner"></span></span>
```

However, the following will look like different ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73opLnrq/1/)):

```
<span class="outer ib">FOO BAR
    <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

```
<span class="outer">FOO BAR
    <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: So who is implementing it correctly? FF or Chrome and Safari?

Comment: @amayem Not sure. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous) says "*Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline element. (...) White space content that would subsequently be collapsed away according to the `white-space` property does not generate any anonymous inline boxes.*". I didn't find what happens with text inside an inline element.

Comment: I think I found it. They seem to both be correct. Under [section 16.6.1 The 'white-space' processing model of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model) It mentions that *"If 'white-space' is set to 'normal' or 'nowrap', linefeed characters are transformed for rendering purpose into one of the following characters: a space character, a zero width space character (U+200B), or no character (i.e., not rendered), according to UA-specific algorithms based on the content script."*